# Close an already open excel file c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a Boolean variable (fileStatus) currently which outputs true when an excel file is open and false when the excel file is closed. When the excel file is open, I want to be able to close it. I have tried the simple for loop:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = null;
if (fileStatus)
            {              
                excelApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
                excelApp.Quit();
                
            }
```

I have also tried the following lines:

```
excelApp.Visible = false;
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

as well as other ways of opening a workbook and closing everything off. I am not sure how to just simply close the application if it is open without opening and initializing a new separate file.